# Opening MySQL in Python on Mac

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to extract information from a MySQL database in Python but it keeps giving me this error:

```
 File "/Users/guest/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 240, in _auth_switch_request
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)

ProgrammingError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have already reset the password and it still gives me the same error. I'm using MySQL through MAMP, in case that's relevant in any way.

Comment: Pretty much what it says the username ans password you have chosen doesn't have access ot the database

Comment: @e4c5 Does it matter if there are anonymous users? I checked and there is one empty user and password. Not sure if this will help.

Comment: Mysql users are not system users. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html